# Rails blank column name during query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm working with Rails and Postgres, and in the process of loading and processing data, I had to create the table and insert the data manually (well, scripted, but the point is I didn't use Rails/migrations).  I have a correctly defined model, but doing things like:

`Coordinator.find(123)` returns:

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...tors".* FROM "coordinators"  WHERE "coordinators"."" = $1 LI...
: SELECT  "coordinators".* FROM "coordinators"  WHERE "coordinators"."" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, there should be missing a line on your model that make this link between your table and activerecord, kinda something like this:

```
class Coordinator > ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "coordinators"
  ... # stuff
end
```

Edit by pcragone:

I just want to add in that running

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:schema:dump
```

appears to have fixed the problem without setting the table name

Comment: but why should I have to set the column name for this model, as opposed to all the other models?  Why doesn't ActiveRecord pick up on the table automatically?

I should that that does fix my problem, but if you could explain why it's necessary I would definitely appreciate it!

Comment: Sincerely, i don't know. hahaha. Maybe it is an inflection problem.

Comment: If you could accept it later, could help some people with the same problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to - also, looks like running `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:schema:dump` allows ActiveRecord to find the correct tables and columns.

Comment: ActiveRecord by default uses plural of the table name so this should be ok without setting table name, unless ofcourse there is something in inflactions that changes the plural of "coordinator" to something else other than "coordinators"